# Apple APNS Silent/Background Notification with Alert Content - How to make both works

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios13

Hi I'm curious to know if anybody has send a APNS push to your phone with payload like:

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : "New Content.",
    "badge" : 9,
    "content-available" : 1
},
"acme1" : "bar",
"acme2" : 42 }
}
```

And get your app to call

```
 application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

successfully but never see a banner / alert on the lock screen
How do you at the same time have it show the alert?

Thanks!

Comment: You can generate notifications locally. Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

Comment: Is it the best practice? just want to make sure I'm not missing something. from my trial and error is I have to create a calendar trigger with at least a second after now time. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are trying to do. If you're always gonna show a notification, consider using regular pushes and a Notification Service Extension instead of silent pushes (use mutable-content instead of content-available). Silent pushes are extremely unreliable, they may be delayed or even never delivered.

Comment: Thanks does notification service extension runs on the background too?

Comment: Yes it does run in the background, but it will ALWAYS present a notification to the user. You can edit its text, make it produce no sound nor vibration, but the notification banner will always be shown to the user, so keep that in mind.